# Algorithm to divide a rectangle to smaller retangles?

Tags: c, algorithm

What's the algorithm to divide a rectangle (c `struct` with 4 `int`s) to a random number of smaller rectangles (return a list of `struct`s)? Even better if the max and min dimension of the smaller rectangles can be controlled by a parameter.

e.g.

```
+----------+            +-------+--+
|          |            |       |  |
|          |            |       |  |
|          |    -->     |---+---+--| (good)
|          |            |   |      |
|          |            +---+      |
|          |            |   |      |
+----------+            +---+------+
```

smaller shapes should be 4-sided, the following is not good:

```
+----------+            +-------+--+
|          |            |       |  |
|          |            |       |  |
|          |    -->     |---+---+--| (not good)
|          |            |          |
|          |            +---+      |
|          |            |   |      |
+----------+            +---+------+
```

Thanks!

Appendix: (rectangle for Moron's discussion)

```
  +----+--------+
  |    |        |
  |    +---+----+
  |    |   |    | (rectangle-chase)
  +----+---+    |
  |        |    |
  +--------+----+
```

Comment: Are there any constraints on how the smaller rectangles should be structured?

Comment: I don't code in C, but it seems to me that recursively dividing rectangles into 2 rectangles should do the job.

Comment: @andand the size of smaller rectangle should be restricted by upper and lower bound parameters, i.e. not smaller than % of the parent rectangle in x-axis, not bigger than % of the parent rectangle in x-axis, not smaller than % of the parent rectangle in y-axis, not bigger than % of the parent rectangle in y-axis

Comment: @Horace: The accepted answer misses some configurations (see my comment to that answer).

Comment: Is a small rectangle in the center of a larger rectangle acceptable? Do you want every *number* of sub-rectangles to be equally probable, or every *configuration* of sub-rectangles to be equally probable?  Must every valid configuration be potentially reachable?

Comment: @Danny Pflughoeft A small rectangle in the center of a larger rectangle is acceptable. But I think the algorithm in accepted answer will not generate one though.

Comment: @Moron I think the answer is good enough for me. I don't need to generate every combination of rectangles (such as the chase one). I only need to break big rectangle into smaller ones. Of course, it's welcomed to provide another answer which can do better than the accepted one and I will up-vote accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split the rectangle into two. Recurse.

Comment: @amphetamachine: The end condition here is so obvious it doesn't really need to be spelled out - after all, you can't split '1' in half without having either '0' or something that can't be represented as an integer.

Comment: @amphetamachine Agree with Anon. The end condition is obvious. The poster even specified the rectangle was specified by integer coordinates. This likely means that all the internal rectangles should also have integer coordinates.

Comment: Err.. This does not work. It misses some configurations. Something like the chase bank logo, but completed to form a rectangle. http://bp1.blogger.com/_YdwmIhUxTJY/R6PknAooqlI/AAAAAAAAAco/k6jOGsQOT48/s400/chase-logo.jpg. Sorry don't have a better description, but I suppose you get the idea: A square in the middle with each side of the square extended to touch exactly one side of the main rectangle.

Comment: @Moron I don't get your point. The chase bank logo does not start as a rectangle anyway.

Comment: @Horace: Think of a rectangle with four corners snipped off which looks like the chase bank logo. The white square in the middle + the 4 blue (if completed to form rectangles) cannot be formed with this solution. Sorry, hard to do geometry with text.

Comment: @Moron "a rectangle with four corners snipped off" is not a rectangle, right?

Comment: @Horace: Chase logo = rectangle with four corners snipped off. Take chase logo, get back the rectangle by adding back the four corners that were snipped off. If you read my comment: "Something like chase logo, but *completed* to form a rectangle". Is it clearer now?

Comment: @Moron I added an appendix with the logo I can think of. is that what you mean?

Comment: @Horace Ho You should have a look into kd-trees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd_tree What You're trying to achieve is basically a kd-tree with k=2

Comment: @Horace: Exactly! That is what I meant.

Comment: @Dave: No. Kd-trees basically give the same solution as this one. See my comment on that answer.

Comment: Yep, they give the same solution as this one and this one is the one that the op is looking for ;)

Comment: @Dave: This answer was accepted before @Moron's objection; it is indeed incorrect.  Besides, just because OP accepted an answer doesn't mean we should stop looking for better (or correct) answers

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit odd to ask this question without specifying what conditions under which the rectangles are split.

However, I suspect that what you're looking for is a kd-tree. The kd-tree is a binary tree in which nodes are split with two resulting child nodes based on a condition.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree

There's also a quad-tree which can be slightly simpler to implement. It involves splitting nodes into 4 equal-sized children. Each child is recursively split this way until some stop condition.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

[Edit: Updated in response to op's edits.]
For what you are doing, might it be simpler to start off dividing the rectangle into an even grid and decide which elements to merge? Basically a bottom-up approach: simply pick one and start merging adjacent cells randomly. Don't do this for cells which have already been traversed, and the merged structure should have a width and height so that expanding a 2x1-cell grid will expand to 2x2 or 3x1 to ensure you constantly keep a 4-sided rectangle shape for the merged node.

If you want a fancier approach, you can approach this like a kd-tree and build it top-down but you'd need to be merging whole sub-trees as you're splitting based on random conditions and the min/max width/height parameter.

Comment: kd-trees have the same problem as the accepted solution. Consider the root node. If you split on x you have a vertical line dividing the rectangle. If you split on y, you have a horizontal line dividing the rectangle. In fact, this solution is not much different from the accepted one.

Comment: @Moron I don't see where the problem with this solution is. Please post an answer describing the problem with the suggested/accepted solutions and provide Your own one, omitting the problem. I fail to see the problem, because given the question I think the op never would want to create something that looks like the case You described. So kd-trees are sufficient for his purposes.

Comment: @Dave: The OP never said anything about not wanting rectangles like in the appendix (but I suppose we will know soon). In any case, this kd-tree solution is same as the accepted solution. You are in effect, splitting the rectangle into two and recursing. Sorry, unless I have an answer, I won't post one, hence the comments...

Comment: Every sane person knows that both answers mean the same. Since the op accepted this kind of solution, he seems to be satisfied with its limits. Stop complaining. My compliments to the choice of Your user name.

Comment: @Dave. Oh please... Anyway I will stop having this discussion with you. Pointless and a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

Choose a random point p on one edge and divide the rectangle there with a line to the opposite edge.  You can then recurse on both halves, stopping the recursion randomly or at a specified limit.